# Need to use "having" instead of where

Tags: mysql, sql

I have simplified the query I am firing for brevity as follows

```
SELECT
  1 AS mae
FROM
  (SELECT
     t.id
   FROM transaction t) a
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT
     track_id
   FROM attendee) AS b ON a.id = b.track_id
HAVING mae > 0;
```

Over here there is no aggregation. However, I still have to use having. If I use where, mysql is unable to recognize the column mae.

Why is this so?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/problems-with-alias.html - about `WHERE` and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html about extensions to standard SQL (including `HAVING`).

Comment: if you are using an left outer join on dataset b, then aren't you just performing a count on table a?

Comment: @PM77-1I did not understand the relevance of the reference you have provided I am not performing any aggregate functions here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, aliases defined in the `SELECT` clause are not available for re-use in the same `SELECT` -- nor in the `WHERE`, nor in the `ON` clauses.  This is a true of all SQL dialects.  Aliases are allowed in the `ORDER BY`, on the other hand.

MySQL recognizes column aliases in the `HAVING` clause.  This is so convenient that MySQL has extended the `HAVING` clause for use with non-aggregation queries.  So, your query is using this extension.

One nice feature of this extension is that it allows the reference without using a subquery -- the normal way around this.  Because MySQL materializes (almost) all derived tables, this saves overhead in the processing.

Answer (score -2):

Ae you just trying to do a regular join ?

```
SELECT *
FROM  transaction t
JOIN attendee AS b 
ON a.id = b.track_id
```